# linux installation blinking screen

Tags: linux, debian

On a new desktop, I have just installed a copy of netinst debian squeeze, however during startup boot, I choose to enter linux but all it showed was a black flashing or blinking screen, and nothing else. I tried to update the kernel but the problem still the same. How to troubleshoot this problem?

While on another laptop I installed the same thing, there was no desktop interface though. For this one the installation might have been corrupted somewhere?

Comment: have you tried verifying [check/hash]sum of the installation image?

Comment: My guess: X is respawning several times and that makes your screen flash everytime it starts. If so you should check your logs and find out why it is crashing.